# cannot open file generated by PHPReport and PHPExcel

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have used the PHPReport library content with the PHPExcel Library content. I am creating the website locally on my macbook using Xampp. The following code I wrote to fetch the data and generate the excel sheet:

```
 public function fetchReportData($newStartDate, $newEndDate){
    if ($this->getDBConnection()) {
         $q = "select * from PMA where request_date between '".$newStartDate."' and '".$newEndDate ."'";
         $r = mysqli_query($this->dbc, $q);
        if ($r) {
            $row_count = $r->num_rows;
            if ($row_count == 0) {
                echo '<div align="left">'
                . '<b><font color="red">* </font>No requests were found in this period</b></div>';
            } else {
                $data = array();
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
                   $desc = $this->returnDesc($row[0]);
                   $requestId = $this->getNormalReqID($row[0]);
                   $this->get($requestId);
                   $username = $this->getUserName($this->requestor_id);
                   $srv_id =  $this->getSRVId($row[0]);
                   $this->getSRV($srv_id);
                   $srv_date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($this->srv_date));
                   $srv = 'SRV dtd '.$srv_date;
                   if($this->srv_remarks == null)
                   {
                       $remark = $srv;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       $remark = $this->srv_remarks;
                   }
                   $data[] =
                    array("Date" => $row[2], "Originator" => $username, "Material No" => $this->material_number,
                        "Description" => $desc, "Quantity" => $row[5], "Order Number" => $this->pm_order_number,
                        "Request Number" => $row[7], "Gate Pass No"=> $row[10], "Gate Pass Date"=> $row[14],
                        "SRV/Date" => $srv, "Received Qty" => $row[11], "Remarks" => $remark)
                       ;

                }
                include_once 'PHPReport.php';
                $R=new PHPReport();
                    $R->load(array(
                        'id'=>'product',
                        'header'=>array(
                            'Date'=>'Date', 'Originator' => 'Originator', 'Material No' => 'Material No',
                        'Description' =>  'Description' , 'Quantity' => 'Quantity', 'Order Number' => 'Order Number',
                        'Request Number' => 'Request Number', 'Gate Pass No' => 'Gate Pass No', 'Gate Pass Date'=> 'Gate Pass Date',
                        'SRV/Date' => 'SRV/Date' , 'Received Qty' => 'Received Qty', 'Remarks' => 'Remarks'
                     ),
                'footer'=>array(
                'Date'=>'', 'Originator' => '', 'Material No' => '',
                        'Description' =>  '' , 'Quantity' => '', 'Order Number' => '',
                        'Request Number' => '', 'Gate Pass No' => '', 'Gate Pass Date'=> '',
                        'SRV/Date' => '' , 'Received Qty' => '', 'Remarks' => ''

            ),

        'data'=> $data

        )
    );

echo $R->render('excel');




            }
    }
    }
}
```

It does not show any error while calling the code and it generates the xlsx sheet fine but I cannot open the file. I get the following error when I try to open the sheet:

The format or file extension is not valid. verify that the file has not been corrupted and the file extension matches the format of the file.

I get the same error while trying to open a PDF created by the library PHP to PDF, is it something wrong with my macbook?

Comment: Open the file in a text editor: look for leading or trailing whitespace characters, any BOM header, or any plaintext messages (such as PHP error messages) in the file data